# PDFTron to keep informations from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pdftron

I need to build a PDF with tooltips using PDFTron (i will use simple text annotations). Objects and their tooltips are stored into entities. I use Convert.ToPDF() method to convert my FlowDocument and inner bindings into a PDF. That works well.

But i also need, as soon as the PDF is generated, to annotate some defined parts of the PDF with the associated tooltips data. The problem is that i cannot find a way to find which PDF element i have to annotate, as none of the XAML markups are kept into PDF. Is there a "Key" concept in PDF ?

For example, suppose i have a UserControl with a TextBlock Inside, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" x:Name="TB00"/>
```

Then, while export to PDF is required, i begin with converting my instanced UserControl to a FixedDocument. That's OK, i can found the 'Name' attribute in my Glyphs fixed document markup, but my tooltip information is lost because it's not in the specifications.

```
<Glyphs Name="TB00" UnicodeString="binding value" />
```

Then, when i use PDFTron (or another converter) to convert my FixedDocument, the name 'TB00' information is also lost in the final PDF.

As i need to create a PDF annotation (stamp or else) to simulate my original XAML tooltip, i must find which tooltip information goes on which PDF element. But i can't... because the name 'TB00' has been lost...

I there a way to control how the PDF conversion is done (subclassing pdftron.PDF.Convert seems useless) without re-inventing the converter ?